# Exponential CDF to a higher power of $X$

Tags: probability, integration, exponential-function

$X$ follwing an exponential distribution

I am requested to compute $P(X^3\le x)$

What I do is to take the pdf, substitute like this  $P(( Y=X^3) \le x)$

And end up with this pdf= $\int \frac{1}{3x^{2}}\lambda e^{-\lambda x^{3}}$

Is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guide:

Taking cube root,

\begin{align}
P(X^3 \le x) &= P(X \le x^\frac13)
\end{align}

Now you just have to use the CDF of $X$ to compute this quantity.

Comment: Thank you, this is of course simpler.

However, If I want to have the pdf of X^3, is my equation correct?

Thanks

Comment: hmm....I don't quite follow how you get your equation. My usual strategy is first compute the CDF then differentiate to get the pdf if I want it.

Comment: taking $Y=X^3$   we have $ \frac{dy}{dx}= 3x^2 \Leftrightarrow  dx= \frac{1}{3x^{2}}dy$

substituting in pdf I get
$\int \frac{1}{3x^{2}}\lambda e^{-\lambda x^{3}}$

Comment: I see, what is the integration with respect to?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have attempted to do this:$$\begin{align}
 f_{X^n}(x) &=\lvert\dfrac{\mathrm d ~~}{\mathrm d x}\mathsf P(X^n\leq x)\rvert \\ &=\lvert\dfrac{\mathrm d ~~}{\mathrm d x}\mathsf P(X\leq x^{1/n})\rvert
&&\text{if $n\in\Bbb N^+$}
\\ &=\lvert\dfrac{\mathrm d ~~}{\mathrm d x}\int_0^{x^{1/n}} \lambda \exp(-\lambda~s)~\mathrm d s\rvert\cdot\mathbf 1_{x\in(0;\infty)}
\end{align}$$
Next, apply the universal principle of calculus.

> $$\begin{align}f_{X^n}(x) &=\lvert\dfrac{\mathrm d x^{1/n}}{\mathrm d x}\rvert\cdot\lambda \exp(-\lambda~x^{1/n})\cdot\mathbf 1_{x\in(0;\infty)}\end{align}$$